# TurtleBot USB Connection - No Data

Tags: usb, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to get a Roomba 555 with Turtlebot power board to work, but keep getting the following message:

"Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create."

I connected the Turtlebot to a Dell Inspiron 6400, running Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS diamondback.
My serial device looks like this:
crw-rw-rw- 1 root mate 188, 0 2011-11-03 10:48 /dev/ttyUSB0

As listed in lsusb:
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

I've tried the traditional fixes, such as restarting, unplugging-replugging, looked at dmesg, but no clues.

Any ideas how I could fix this would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Máté

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11783/turtlebot-usb-connection---no-data/) by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check that the iRobot Create is turned on. ( The green light should be on next to the power button.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-15**:
@mate did this work for you?

**Comment by [madmarc](https://answers.ros.org/users/22466/madmarc/) on 2015-05-18**:
Hi ROS community !
I have the same problem here, on an eu turtlebot 1 (based on roomba 521).
I think is correctly turned on and i can see the ttyUSB0 file in /dev.
I think is cause of the board, it's an old turtlebot.eu card on which I can't find any information on the internet.

Thx !